# AngularJS: How to dynamically add a function to a appended html element within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive for handling all links across my web app. I have successfully generated different link objects depending on what role the logged in user have. The following code works, except when I try to add functionality to ng-click within "htmlElement".

```
      $scope.test = test;
      function test() {
                console.log("test")
            }

       var htmlElement = "<li ng-click=\"test()"\"><a href=\"" +
                link.href + "\" target=\"" +
                link.target + "\">" +
                link.title + "</a></li>";
       element.append(htmlElement);
...
       $compile(element)($scope);
       element.append(element);
```

When hitting the generated element, ng-click and test() does not fire. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add a http://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is modifying the DOM directly.  Don't do that. Use ng-show or ng-if to control whether your `<li>` should appear, not jQuery-style DOM manipulation.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with manipulating the DOM inside a directive. That's why directives are made. `ng-show`/`ng-if` add watches. his solution does not.

Comment: Are you using isolate scope? and your click callback defined inside directive or in parent controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the **test()** function on the directive's scope, like so:

```
       $scope.test = function() {
                console.log("test")
            }

       var htmlElement = "<li ng-click=\"test()"\"><a href=\"" +
                link.href + "\" target=\"" +
                link.target + "\">" +
                link.title + "</a></li>";
       element.append(htmlElement);
```

...

```
   $compile(element)($scope);
   element.append(element);
```

**test()** is a private function within the directive's link function. It isn't accessible by the ng-click because it is not on the $scope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I have tried this but still cant seem to get it to work. The generated html in the browser looks like this 

<li ng-click="test()"><a href="#/" target="_self">Logga ut</a></li>

which is correct, however still no reaction when pressing the link.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are trying to display a button whether the user has the required role to see or use the button.
This is not a good way with what you are trying to do.

The approach is the following:
Add a scope where the role for the user is stored, then inside the controller evaluate it (if the user can see the button). Then use ng-show inside the html to hide/view the button.

Example:
(inside of html)

```
<!-- when $scope.myValue is truthy (element is visible) -->
<div ng-show="userRole"></div>
```

Instead of the div use your button or whatever you want to...

(inside of your controller or script)

```
<script>
if (user.Role == "Admin")
{ 
   // this will show the button on the view
   $scope.userRole = true 
}
else
{
   // this will hide the button from the view
   $scope.userRole = false;
}
</script>
```